# Skip Friday in Fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I want to hide Friday in full calendar. Suppose In Dubai Friday is holiday. So how can i hide Friday from full calendar

Answer (score 0):

try this hack, either put it in your own css, or add to fullcalendar.css

.fc-fri { display:none; }

this assuming you already set weekends = true. But i dont know if this will mess up event rendering if you have things that extend through Friday...

failing that, modify fullcalendar.js and look for "weekends", and an extra day to skipWeekend.

Comment: when i change in skipweekend method and give friday as weekend. but when i put event in saturday slot it will display me date as friday. so i am getting wrong date.