# Skip Friday in Fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

when I change in skipweekend method and give friday as weekend. but when I put event in saturday slot it will display me date as friday. so I am getting wrong date

Comment: What FullCalendar is this? What language are you programming in? There are multiple libraries/projects/programs/apps called FullCalendar.

Comment: which language ? what is the context?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Skip Friday in Fullcalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755889/skip-friday-in-fullcalendar)

Answer (score 0):

Usually it uses 0-based structures.